# Undefined variables in PHP template

Tags: php, templates, undefined

I use PHP as a template language in my view layer,
Is it possible to make the following a little cleaner and more concise?

```
//in temp.phtlm
<?= (isset($user['name'])) ? $user['name'] : null; ?>
```

Unfortunately, we can not even define a function for that:

```
// as you know yet a notice is generated when calling a function with an undefined parameter
function echo($var)
{
        return (isset($var)) ? $var : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `@` operator is the shortest alternative.

```
<?= @$user['name']; ?>
```

Since PHP 7 you can also use the `??` operator.

```
<?= $user['name'] ?? null; ?>
```

Which does exactly what the `@` operator does, though a bit longer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no short hand method to do that quicker, no. Any other method would throw an error if $var did not exist at that point.

Depending on your structure/templating system you could use a class to store your var's and use the magic methods __get, __set, __isset, __unset to call your variables. Those methods could then just return null if the var didnt exist. This would require quite a change in your code though. You can find the manual about magic methods here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

As for your original code, i would write it like this:

```
<?php echo ( isset($var) ? $var : null ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, Is it also applicable to undefined array elements?

Comment: No, normally you will need to use isset for array indexis.

Answer (score 2):

```
//in temp.phtlm
<?=$var?>

//in whatever_your_script_name.php
$template->var = isset($var) ? htmlentities(whatever(convert(encode($var)))) : '';
$template->render('temp.phtml');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it so you won't be prompted that the variable is undefined:

```
$args = $args ?? null;
```

Comment: For reference, see [Null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).